# How to order 3d points in clockwise order?

Tags: arrays, 3d, point

I have bunch of 3d points (an array) not ordered in some particular order and not restricted to some axis/plane. Based on the coordinates of these points I want to order the array in clockwise order, like in the image. At moment I am clueless where to start. One idea is to find for each the closest point and somehow figure out the direction.

[image]

Comment: `3D points?` "Clockwise" doesn't really mean anything in 3D without a common frame of reference, like a view plane.

Comment: Just for the record, note too that even if they are on a plane, clockwise depends on which side you are looking from !!

Comment: @Fattie I assumed that the plane would have a normal. :)

Comment: heh!  well it has 2 directions eh !  CW on one side and CCW on the other

Comment: Reminds me of working on a car. The "left" side is from the driver's point of view, when sitting in the seat. If you're working under the hood (in a front engine car), the "left" side is on your right. This makes interpreting service manual instructions pretty entertaining.

Comment: @trshmanx You're going to need more constraints in order to be able to provide a general solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3Dave has already said this, but it completely depends on where the camera is.

There is no answer unless you specify the frustrum.

Note that circles are 2D, not 3D objects.  "Clockwise" relates to circles.

---

## Assuming that you mean on a plane:

This is a problem with two parts.

The first part is incredibly difficult.

The second part is relatively easy.

First part: indeed, you are doing object recognition: you have to find a circle.

For this, investigate **the existing technology** for shape recognition, or read up on stuff like https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11042-018-6167-2

For the second part: (which is almost irrelevant after the first part).  Just get the coords of each point relative to the *center* of the circle you found, simply calculate the angle of each from the top, and sort them.

---

## Cheap game-type solution

If you want the cheap solution, which you can use **if the points are "reasonable"** ..

1. find the centroid of all the points *(it's just the average of all)*
2. write each point as a vector from the centroid to the point
3. pick any one point as being the "top"
4. use something like this https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Angle.html to get the angle of each from the "top" one
5. voila!  just put them in order

In practice you'll likely need these things also:

6. find the "plane" the points are on (find the "average plane" they are on, it's relatively easy to do this, look it up!)
7. make an axis through the centroid which is perpendicular to the plane
8. 

Comment: Camera can change. Like going around etc. Depending on that I can figure out the direction, but I just need to order them so all edges are outside.

Comment: @trshmanx - as everyone has said, it's meaningless unless they are all in fact on some plane (or arguably, very close to some plane).  Just imagine (say) the eight points of a cube. How would you "order them in a clockwise manner"?  It's meaningless.

Comment: OK let's assume it's on a Plane, but I don't have it's `center`?

Comment: There's a potential issue here. Imagine a crescent or kidney shape; the "center" won't be within the shape, so you'll wind up with a jagged line rather than a polygon. Which may be acceptable!

Comment: for sure man.  the OP's question is REALLY difficult to answer.  first you have to search (in 3D!) for a circle, otherwise it's a bust.  the "cheap game-type solution" I outline ONLY works if the points are "reasonable" !  if the "cheap game-type solution" doesn't work, he'll have to develop what could only be called a full AI.